# An example of two functions with a certain property

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Do there exist functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

(I) $f,g$ are both strictly monotonically increasing

(II)  $f,g$ both tend to $\infty$ at $\infty$.

(III)  $\limsup \frac{f}{g}$ exists at $\infty$ and is finite.

(IV) $\liminf \frac{f}{g}$ exists at $\infty$ and is positive.

and

(V) $\frac{f}{g}$ oscillates at $\infty$, i.e. $\lim \frac{f}{g}$ does *not* exist!

Many thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: How about something like $f(x)=\sin(x)+x$ and $g(x)=\cos(x)+x$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant the limit exists and is $1$ in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Let $f(x)=x$.  We want $g(x)$ to be oscillating between $x$ and $2x$ in a way that it is always increasing.  Then $\lim \sup \frac fg=1, \lim \inf \frac fg=\frac 12$  One version is $$g(x)=\begin {cases} 1+4(x-1)&1\le x \lt \frac 32\\\frac 25(x-\frac 32)+3&\frac 32 \le x \lt 4 \end {cases}$$ then for $x \gt 4$, divide $x$ by the proper $4^n$ to get it within $[1,4)$, find $g$ of that value, and multiply by $4^n$ again